# SharePoint 2010 MetaInfo field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I am looking at "MetaInfo" field of SharePoint 2010 document and what I found out that all date fields are being stored in below format. What I am interested in parsing this value to actual date.

> FX|0x01d27086|0xefe73000
>
> FX|0x01d1dc0b|0x0198d800

Is there a way I can convert this valid DateTimetetime object?

Below is the sample code on fetching "MetaInfo"

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);

    clientContext.Load(spList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var item = spList.GetItemById(1);
    Console.WriteLine(item["MetaInfo"]);
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this MetaInfo? From the content database column `MetaInfo` or `ows_MetaInfo` in an item's XML schema? The above MetaInfo looks incomplete.

Comment: I am using SharePoint CSOM and seeing this as one of the field of SharePont's Item object

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive? Are you seeing this in `SPItem.Properties`? Somewhere else?

Comment: Updated my question with sample code.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the value is generated and compressed within unmanaged code so I'm not sure what format the value represents -- it doesn't appear to represent filetime, which is how OpenXml stores the value.

Answer (score -1):

MetaInfo is a field that contains the metadata information that is associated with the SharePoint list item.

It returns value in GUID format and not date format.

```
public static readonly Guid MetaInfo
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked.